# How to initialize an instance when ember creates the object

Tags: ember.js, breeze

I'm trying to add a simple breeze.js datastore to my ember project and I'd like to register it something like ember-data does today. I have a working example so far, the only issue I'm having is that I needed to set the "instance" inside my store manually and then reference it like so

> "this.store.instance.something()"

instead of what I'd prefer

> "this.store.something()"

What am I doing incorrectly below?

```
App.BreezeStore = Ember.Object.extend({
    instance: null,
    init: function() {
        var ds = new breeze.DataService({
            serviceName: 'api',
            hasServerMetadata: false,
            useJsonp: false
        });
        breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance("modelLibrary", "backingStore", true);
        this.instance = new breeze.EntityManager({dataService: ds});
        this.instance.metadataStore.addEntityType({
            shortName: "Session",
            namespace: "App",
            dataProperties: {
                id: { dataType: "Int64", isPartOfKey: true },
                name: { dataType: "String" }
            }
        });
    }
});

Ember.onLoad('Ember.Application', function(Application) {

    Application.initializer({
        name: "store",

        initialize: function(container, application) {
            application.register('store:main', App.BreezeStore);
        }
    });

    Application.initializer({
        name: "injectStore",
        before: "store",

        initialize: function(container, application) {
            application.inject('controller', 'store', 'store:main');
            application.inject('route', 'store', 'store:main');
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember's container was designed so that you're really only supposed to register Ember subclasses as factories. But if you don't mind a bit of a hack, there is a way to achieve what you want. You just need to create a fake factory that will give the container the object you want it to have when it calls `create`.

```
initialize: function(container, application) {
    var factory = {
        create: function() {
            return App.BreezeStore.create().instance;
        }
    };

    application.register('store:main', factory);
}
```

So when the container instantiates the singleton store, it'll call `create` on your fake factory which will return the `instance` variable from above. So now your `store:main` value will be the value you're expecting.

But as a pitfall, this means that you won't be able to access any properties or methods that you define on the `BreezeStore` class, but I'm assuming that you weren't doing that anyway. If you need to be able to access those, you could always register and inject two different stores.